# Sort Array Subkey Based on Another Array's Order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I know there have been many posts regarding array sorting, but I have looked high and low and cannot find a solution to my problem.

**I have found a very good article here:**
http://firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/

The above link is great, however, I wish to take it further and sort the array subkey based off the order of another array.

**So, let's say we have five songs in the Playlist Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3oh!3 - Don't Trust me
    [1] => Taylor Swift - You Belong with me
    [2] => Sean Kingston - Fire Burning
    [3] => Green Day - Know Your Enemy
    [4] => Kelly Clarkson - Gone
)
```

**And let's say we have the following information that we would like sorted to match the order of our Playlist Array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trackName] => Taylor Swift - You Belong With Me
            [trackLength] => 0
            [trackViews] => 0
            [trackRating] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trackName] => Sean Kingston - Fire Burning
            [trackLength] => 0
            [trackViews] => 0
            [trackRating] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [trackName] => 3OH!3- Dont Trust Me 
            [trackLength] => 205
            [trackViews] => 4570399
            [trackRating] => 4.866372
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [trackName] => Green Day Know Your Enemy 
            [trackLength] => 191
            [trackViews] => 4715494
            [trackRating] => 4.9103785
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [trackName] => Kelly Clarkson: Gone 
            [trackLength] => 225
            [trackViews] => 679019
            [trackRating] => 4.8995433
        )

)
```

So, again... My question is: How can I get the array of songs to be sorted by the trackName to match the same order of the Playlist Array?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks.

**[SOLUTION]**
EDDIE had the master winning solution! Props to him! 1up his answer! :)

However, I modified eddie's solution slightly. I just added a similarity check of 75% between the user entered song titles and the song titles looked up on the external sources because I cannot control the slight variations of each title.

```
$sorted_list = array();

foreach($songs as $song_key=>$song){
   foreach($song_info as $info){
      similar_text($info['trackName'], $song, $p);
      if($p > 75){ 
        $sorted_list[$song_key] = $info;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why would you need to do this? You have the information from the first array in the second..

Comment: The order of the second array gets scrambled upon gathering the data from multiple sources. I need it to be sorted the same as the user entered it from the get go. :)

Comment: Aha, okay - check my code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your playlist is in the array $songs and your other array is in $songs_info.

```
$sorted_list = array();

foreach($songs as $song_key=>$song){
   foreach($song_info as $info){
      if($info['trackName'] == $song){
          $sorted_list[$song_key] = $info;
      }
   }
}

// $sorted_list contains sorted list
```

Comment: Eddie, your code is throwing errors. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() referring to this line: `foreach($song_info as $info){` what is $song_info??

Comment: I'm not magic - I couldn't guess your array names.. Checkout my edit's above.. $song_info should be replaced with the name of the array holding your second lot of data..

Comment: Okay my apologies for misunderstanding at first. However, your method appears to only be returning ONE song in the vardump?

Comment: Eddie, I changed a bit inside the second foreach(), just added a similarity check of 75% and it works flawlessly now! Thanks man! Really appreciate it!! `   similar_text($info['trackName'], $song, $p);
   if($p > 75){ 
    $sorted_list[$song_key] = $info;
   }`

Answer (score 2):

You get the weight in sort from the position of each trackname in the playlist.

So you need to find each track inside the playlist (position) to get the weight of a track in the track-list.

You can then use that order to sort the track-list ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fPDrgO)):

```
$playlist = array
(
    '3OH!3- Don\'t Trust Me',
    'Taylor Swift - You Belong With Me',
    'Sean Kingston - Fire Burning',
    'Green Day - Know Your Enemy',
    'Kelly Clarkson - Gone',
);

$tracks = array
(
    array('trackName' => 'Taylor Swift - You Belong With Me'),
    array('trackName' => 'Sean Kingston - Fire Burning'),
    array('trackName' => '3OH!3- Don\'t Trust Me'),
    array('trackName' => 'Green Day - Know Your Enemy'),
    array('trackName' => 'Kelly Clarkson - Gone'),
);

$order = array_map(function($track) use ($playlist) {
    return array_search($track['trackName'], $playlist);
;}, $tracks);

array_multisort($order, $tracks);

var_dump($tracks);
```

**Note:** This does only work when the trackname in the playlist is the same as the trackname inside the track-list. With the example data you gave in your question, that was not the case.

Additionally I simplified your `$tracks` data a bit, each element can have any amount of additional elements naturally.

Comment: hakre, could you use the similar_text() function to check 75% similarity of the trackName?? I cannot control the slight variations of each track name. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Then you would need to create an additional routine that returns the index of the most matching element (and use it instead of `array_search`).

Answer (score 1):

it is not effectivily but should works:

```
usort($songsArray,function($a,$b){
    return array_search($a['trackName'],$GLOBALS['playlistarray'])-array_search($b['trackName'],$GLOBALS['playlistarray']);
});
```

Hakre's idea:

```
usort($songsArray,function($a,$b) use($playlistarray){
    return array_search($a['trackName'],$playlistarray)-array_search($b['trackName'],$playlistarray);
});
```

Comment: better `use()` than globals perhaps.

Comment: This does only work when the trackname in the playlist is the same as the trackname inside the track-list. With the example data you gave in your question, that was not the case.

Comment: RiaD, what about a 75% similarity check some how? using the similar_text() function?? I don't know how to integrate a check, but would that be possible?

Comment: I think it should be other solution. Something like Eddie's one