# Sort multidimensional array by unidimensindal array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The multidim. array looks like:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    'id' => 'first',
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 17,
  ),

  array(
    'id' => 'second',
    'name' => 'Mary',
    'age' => 26,
  ),

  array(
    'id' => 'third',
    'name' => 'Eve',
    'age' => 21,
  ),

);
```

And the array which decides how `$arr` is sorted looks like:

`$sort_by = array('third', 'first', 'second');`

So what I want is to sort the elements of the first array based on its `id` field and the second array.

In this case the 1st array should be:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    'id' => 'third',
    'name' => 'Eve',
    'age' => 21,
  ),

  array(
    'id' => 'first',
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 17,
  ),

  array(
    'id' => 'second',
    'name' => 'Mary',
    'age' => 26,
  ),


);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Array Subkey Based on Another Array's Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711548/sort-array-subkey-based-on-another-arrays-order)

Answer (score 4):

```
function sort_by_1d($item_1, $item_2)
{
    $sort_by = array('third', 'first', 'second');
    $item_1_i = array_search($item_1['id'], $sort_by);
    $item_2_i = array_search($item_2['id'], $sort_by);
    return $item_1_i - $item_2_i;
}

usort($arr, 'sort_by_1d');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sortedArray = array();
foreach($sort_by as $sort){
  foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val['id'] === $sort){
      $sortedArray[] = $val;
    }
  }
}
```

Stolen from: [Sort Array Subkey Based on Another Array's Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711548/sort-array-subkey-based-on-another-arrays-order/6711780#6711780)